# Externally-powered USB with built in sound card

Tags: usb, macbook, hardware-rec, sound-card

I am after a USB hub with at least 5 ports, and a built in 3.5mm headphone jack so I can use that to reduce the cables hanging out of my Macbook when it is on my desk.

I don't want one that requires me to plug a 3.5mm headphone jack into my Macbook. Is it possible to get a hub that also doubles as a USB 'sound card', so I can plug my speakers into it, but still only have to plug the hub into my Macbook using a single USB cable.

Does such a product exist?

Answer (score 2):

I've not been able to dig up anything that fixes the audio issue within the hub, but I have found several products such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BUDHNQ), which function as USB sound cards.  Perhaps you could pick up a USB hub with six ports and purchase one of those to go with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [USB Sound Card w/ 3 Port USB Hub + Card Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RJYRP8).  I didn't see one with more ports.